# GTest pass std::vector as a parameter source

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a function which reads out all files in a selected directory.

```
std::vector<std::string> getAllFilesInDirectory(const std::string_view strDirectory);
```

Now I'd like to run my tests on each element of that vector.
My test fixture is pretty straight forward.

```
class myTestfixture: public ::testing::TestWithParam<std::string> 
{
public:
  myTestfixture();
  ~myTestfixture() override;
};
```

Now I'd like to pass each element of the vector to my tests. I know I can pass single explicit values to :testing::Values, but passing a stl container does not work.

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
  myTest,
  myTestfixture,
  ::testing::Values(
    getAllFilesInDirectory("myDir")
  ));

TEST_P(myTestfixture, ValidTest)
{
//test something
}
```

Is it even possible to pass containers as a parameter source to gtest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done it but with a small mistake. Try to use `ValuesIn()` instead of `Values()`.

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
  myTest,
  myTestfixture,
  ::testing::ValuesIn(
    getAllFilesInDirectory("myDir")
  ));
```